# SHA256 Base64 Hash in Ruby

Tags: c#, ruby, cryptography, sha256, sha

We are trying to implement the SHA256 Base64 hash in ruby which is not returning the expected results as in C#.

Below is our C# sample code.

```
    public static string HashSHA256ToBase64(string phrase)
    {
        if (phrase == null)
            return null;
        var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        var sha256Hasher = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        var hashedDataBytes = sha256Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(phrase));

        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedDataBytes);
    }
```

For this, we need to write equivalent code in ruby. For which we are trying as follows.

```
Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), "", phrase))
```

It is not providing the same results as C#.

Test phrase : V2dcZBpzzglD1ynW5ZAyFocs9wtpR624wlla9gujw0I=RquZ/QzazPM=

Expected Result : utXwt733s9FmiSM69o2zGOm0IT42FjthbB0oquIuPak=

Can someone help me with the equivalent ruby code to resolve this

Comment: HMAC-SHA256 is not SHA256.

Comment: I really hope this has absolutely nothing to do with password hashing because SHA256 is dangerously inadequate for that task.

Answer (score 8):

Below code fixed this

```
Digest::SHA256.base64digest(phrase)
```